# Repeating decimal sign

Tags: support, mathjax

Is there a way to type the repeating decimal sign on top of a number on the Mathematics Stack Exchange site? I have a question I want to ask about a repeating decimal and I want to improve the cosmetic aspect of the question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $4.\overline{285714}$? `$4.\overline{285714}$`

Comment: For information on MathJax, see the [MathJax Tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, `\overline` is the way to go: to get
$0.5\overline{332}$, type `$0.5\overline{332}$`.

Comment: So I do not have to add the $ sign at the beginning and end?

Comment: Um, no. You do.  (Let me edit that...)